# Transfer database to new instance aws

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, lamp

I had an aws ec2 instance on which I set up LAMP.Now im creating a new instance and also has detached the ebs from old instance to new.Do i need to again setup lamp in the new instance,or is there a way I can transfer the LAMP setup of old instance to new?

Answer (score 0):

EC2 instances are  built using an image (AMI).

If you do not want to use one of the available AMIs that already has an apache stack, you can make your own image (AMI) from your first EC2 instance.

Then you use this image for your new EC2 instance instead of the one you started with and it will have your LAMP stack.

For very small applications, learning, etc, this works.

You say you set up a LAMP stack.  I recommend you use a separate RDS instance for your database.  EC2 instances should not have your permanent data on them since they can fail or be shut down.  An RDS database will be more reliable.

Depending on what you are doing, Elastic Beanstalk, with it's pre-configured stacks (PHP, Node.js, others) and a separate database service (RDS or one of the others) might be a better solution. There is a method for customizing a Beanstalk environment (adding a special system logging category, a php  environment variable etc.) when instances are started so that you do not need to have a custom AMI.

Beanstalk is a wrapper service that configures from a single EC2 instance to a many instance, scaling, load balanced environment. But be sure you need the other extras that Elastic Beanstalk provides.